# fish: stat: Unable to find a process “Y”

Tags: fish, stat

I try to run the following command in Fish, without success:

```
$ stat -c %Y foo
fish: Unable to find a process “Y”
```

However, in Bash, it works as expected:

```
$ stat -c %Y foo
1548610349
```

I tried to put `%Y` into single or double quotes, even removed the space before it; it won’t work.

I am open to alternative programs, too, that would do the same, however, I’d like to know **why** does it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve just found [this](http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/#escapes} page and `%` must be escaped with backslash in Fish.

Therefore, the following command works as expected:

```
stat -c \%Y foo
```

Comment: Alternatively, upgrade to fish 3.0, where that particular expansion was removed.